# Breaking up large DataGridView for printing

Tags: c#, printing, datagridview

I've got a  single-row, 40 column-long DataGridView that i need to print.

Since i can neither print it directly (because A4 sheets won't cut it ;)) nor adjust its width to the width of the page itself (because the headers look terrible), i wanted to break the DataGridView to 4 separate pieces and display 10 columns per row (imagine: column 1 to 10 in the first line, column 11 to 21 four or five lines below, etc...).

Is there an easy way to do this? I was leaning towards a more manual approach (using fors), but i'd love to know if there's a more elegant way.

Cheers

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Would it be better to pivot the view to give you 40 rows rather than 40 columns?

Comment: Marginally better... It's printable, but looks ugly.